# Sync Ubuntu-touch Tasks with Nextcloud

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, nextcloud

I have managed to sync my Nextcloud contacts with ubuntu-touch using the following commands:

> syncevolution --configure --keyring=no --template webdav
>   username='MY_USERNAME' password='MY_PASSWORD'
>   syncurl="https://MY_URL/nextcloud" target-config@nextcloud
>
> syncevolution --configure --template SyncEvolution_Client sync=none
>   syncURL=local://@nextcloud username= password= nextcloud
>
> syncevolution --configure --template webdav
>   database=https://MY_URL/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/addressbooks/users/MY_USERNAME/default/
>   backend=carddav target-config@nextcloud contacts
>
> syncevolution --configure sync=two-way backend=contacts nextcloud
>   contacts
>
> syncevolution --sync slow nextcloud contacts

**My question is how do I do this for my Nextcloud tasks?** I seem to be getting bogged down with the syncevolution syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found this bug on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/syncevolution/+bug/1440294

So to sync to a cloud task list:

syncevolution --configure database=https://xxx.memkit.com/calendars/yyy/zzz backend=caldavtodo target-config@memkit todo
syncevolution --configure sync=two-way backend=tasks database="Personal" memkit todo
syncevolution --sync slow memkit todo

Unfortunately the Ubuntu-touch task list only shows its own tasks, not the cloud tasks.